# Active Directory medata xml file. How to get it?

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, idp

I am trying to setup SSO for PSM application as per this link - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSL5ES_2.3.2.0/intel/iwd/aat_sec_sso.html

It says I should -  upload the IdP metadata XML file received from the Identity Provider. 
The Identity provider available in-house is Active Directory.

How to get the metadata XML for Active Directory ?

I am unable to find it .

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

ADFS does not provide SAML IdP meta data alone, but Federation meta data. Typically you can get it from https://FQDN_OF_THE_ADFS_SERVER/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Then you need to extract the SAML IdP meta data from it. Alternatively you may reach out to the ADFS admnistrator and request it. Judging from my experience, you mostly also get the Federation meta data, instead of the SAML one.